# how can i clean the cached data from browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching, browser

I am using ajax jquery to submit a form, it works fine but when i submit the form for more than 5 times it makes the browser very slow, i have looked to inspect element it shows me that the more than 5MB data transferred while this amount is 22KB for firs time.
the form and the result area is located in same page there is no refresh on the page. if i refresh the page it work normal but after submitting more than 5 times same thing happens again.
the code is here:

```
$(".btn_search").click(function(){
        if($('#org option:selected' && '#dept option:selected')) {
              $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "showReports",
                     data: $('#search_form').serialize(),
                     cache:false,
                     success : function(response){
                             $("#payroll-assign-rights").html(response);
                             $('#payroll-assign-rights div.box #assign-head-1').next().remove();
                             $('#payroll-assign-rights div.box #assign-head-1').remove();
                             $('#payroll-assign-rights div.box #assign-head-2').remove();
                             $('#payroll-assign-rights div.box #payroll-assign-rights').hide();
                             $("#emp-report").show();
                        }
                });
            }
    });
```

Comment: I think 5MB is very low for a web app. You should store the $() result to avoid multiple query.

Comment: i mean that is increasing by each submit and after 5MB it works very slow